# Is it possible to issue redeem codes for commercial apps in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, commercial

Does the Ubuntu Software Center has some mechanism available to the developers to issue redeem codes (coupons) for commercial applications so that they can be downloaded (and kept updated) via USC for free?

The use case I'm interested in is when a user purchased a license previously on another platform and now wants to use the application on Ubuntu -- it just wouldn't be right to ask them to purchase again.

It seems that some mechanism is in place, because Humble Indie Bundle apparently used it (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200829/cannot-redeem-my-old-humble-indie-bundle-on-usc) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304119/how-do-i-contact-support-about-a-purchase-on-the-ubuntu-sofwtware-center) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1052730), but I don't see anything related in MyApps. That could be because it's still in draft stage, but other bits of UI that aren't functional yet either are already visible there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no such redemption mechanisms in Software Center.

However, for games that are in Steam, if you bought them via Steam on Windows or Mac OS, and they are available for Linux, you can install them there without purchasing again (because the platform in that case is actually "Steam" and not "Linux").

The Humble Bundle delivery via Software Center was a special case done only for Humble Bundle, as Software Center doesn't have support for arbitrary values of payment decided by the purchaser rather than the seller.

Comment: I'm asking as a developer; Steam is not relevant to USC.

Comment: That's really not possible? So the only option would be refund or use an alternate repository with required authentication? Is it to be always the same or is there a plan to change it in the future?